# Module not found : 'child process'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm developing a ReactJS app with Babel and Webpack. I am using the create-react-app facebook script so it handles the Webpack´s configuration. My problem is that I created a js file and add:

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
```

But when I want to compile the new version i get the following error :

```
Module not found: 'child_process'.
```

I don't know what to do with this . I have read that adding custom configurations to the webpack.config.js may be the solution but i am using create react app so I don't have the Webpack configuration. I tried running npm run eject and create my own webpack.config.js but it doesn't work.

I hope somebody could help me.

Comment: make sure you have installed `child_process`. if not `npm install --save child_process`

Comment: `child_process` is built-in Node.js you don't need any module.

Comment: `child_process` is a Node.js (i.e. server-side) module, while I'm assuming your React app is bundled for use in the browser. Because you simply can't launch any child processes in the browser, webpack cannot find the module.

Comment: So is there any workaround for that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure the correct `target` inside the webpack configuration: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './path/to/my/entry/file.js',
  ...
  target: 'node',// we can use node.js modules after adding this configuration
};
```

Comment: What have i do in order to the app uses the webpack conf in the webpack.config.js and not the configuration default bu react create app . I have to modify the package.json scripts, haven't I?

Comment: You can manage the webpack config yourself by running `npm run eject`: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#converting-to-a-custom-setup